# How to append data to an existing partition in BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery

We can create a partition on BigQuery table while creating a BigQuery table.

I have some questions on the partition.

1. How to append data to an existing partition in the BigQuery table.
2. How to create a new Partition in an existing BigQuery table if there is already partition present in that BiQuery table.
3. How to do truncate and load data to a partition in the BigQuery table(overwrite data in a partition in the BigQuery table).

Answer (score 2):

> How to append data to an existing partition in the BigQuery table.

Either you do this from Web UI or with API or with any client of your choice - the approach is the same  - you just set your Destination Table with respective partition decorator, like below as an example

```
yourProject.yourDataset.youTable$20171010
```

Please note: to append your data - you need to use `Append to table` for `Write Preference` under **Advanced Options** (which you need to expand)

> How to create a new Partition in an existing BigQuery table if there is already partition present in that BiQuery table.

If the partition you set in decorator of destination table does not exist yet - it will be added for you

> How to do truncate and load data to a partition in the BigQuery table(overwrite data in a partition in the BigQuery table).

To truncate and load to a specific partition - you should use `Overwrite table` for `Write Preference`

Comment: Hey Mikhail, found your post! Speaking to the last part of your answer: Say I have partitioned by day and I realise I screwed up the upload for today and the data is faulty I would use Overwrite table for Write Preference?

Comment: that's should work (make sure you overwrite only specific partition and not the whole table - like `yourProject.yourDataset.youTable$20180724`) - try and if it does not in your particular case  - please post new question with details of your case

Comment: Thx Mikhail, is it possible that Write Preference was changed to  write disposition

Comment: in BQ UI it is called `Write Preference`; if you are using API - it is called [configuration.query.writeDisposition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.writeDisposition)

Comment: Right, thank you for pointing that out! Mind if I add that to your answer?